# When do I generate new GUID's for COM Servers? (Examples in Python)

Tags: python, com, guid, com-server

I’m new at making COM servers and working with COM from Python so I want to clarify a few things I could not find explicit answers for:

**Creating GUID’s Properly for COM servers**

Do I generate:

1. The GUID for my intended COM server manually, copy it and use that # for the server from then on in? Therefore, when I distribute the application the other users will use the same GUID I created during development.
2. A new GUID each time the application or COM server object is initialized?
3. A new GUID on a per computer basis, only once during the initial setup then have the app save the GUID # and on future loads it pulls that # from the users setup file?

Example Scenario 1:

```
i)  print(pythoncom.CreateGuid())   #in interpreter
ii) _reg_clsid_ = copy  above GUID into your app
```

Example Scenario 2:

```
i)_reg_clsid_ = pythoncom.CreateGuid()
```

Example Scenario 3:

```
if self.isfile = os.path.isfile(url):
    load_previous_generated_GUID(url)
else:
    #first time running application or setup file is missing
    GUID = pythoncom.CreateGuid()
    save_GUID_to_setup_file(GUID)
```

---

**Can I use GUID’s for tracking program/COM server versions?**

If scenario #1 above is correct then:
When I make an upgrade I can test for the old GUID so I can interact with it correctly?

TODO: How do I get the GUID of a COM server from Python and/or VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want scenario 1.  You should generate a CLSID *once* during development, and use that until you change the set of functions your class exports (to COM).

Not only *can* you use CLSIDs for tracking versions, you *must* change the CLSIDs whenever you release a new version, or else you break [COM identity rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); breaking the rules usually results in obscure failure modes when invoking your object out-of-process.

Typically, however, you don't expose CLSIDs directly to code, you expose [PROGIDs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/10/511279.aspx) instead, which are human-readable strings with embedded versioning information, and use the Win32 API [CLSIDFromProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert between the two.  (VBA will do this for you; Python may do this too.)

Comment: The link is to "Wait functions" article.

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. I have not found the identity rules article but MSDN's article called "GUID Creation and Optimizations" provides additional reading on this subject matter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @SteveLee - fixed the link.